# Slidetoggle 2 adjacent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

```
<div class="unique1">Blabla1</div>
<div class="amministrazione">Amministrazione</div>
<a href="">some link</a>
<a href="">some link</a>
<div class="didattica">Didattica</div>
<a href="">some link</a>

<div class="unique2">Blabla2</div>
<div class="amministrazione">Amministrazione</div>
<a href="">some link</a>
<div class="didattica">Didattica</div>
<a href="">some link</a>
<a href="">some link</a>

<div class="unique3">Blabla3</div>
<div class="amministrazione">Amministrazione</div>
<div class="didattica">Didattica</div>

<div class="unique4">Blabla4</div>
<div class="amministrazione">Amministrazione</div>
<div class="didattica">Didattica</div>
<a href="">some link</a>
```

I'd like to have .amministrazione, .didattica and all the links on `display:none` by default. When user clicks on .unique1 or .unique2 or .unique3 or .unique4 (only) the next .amministrazione AND .didattica slidetoggle down.

Here's what I have so far.. but it's not toggling the correct elements:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.unique1, .unique2, .unique3, .unique4').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.amministrazione, .didattica').eq(index).slideDown();
        jQuery('.amministrazione, .didattica').not(newTarget).slideUp();

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rgqpzpt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nextAll` with the `:first` selector to target the appropriate `divs`:

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery('.unique1, .unique2, .unique3, .unique4').click(function () {
    jQuery('.amministrazione, .didattica').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).nextAll('.amministrazione:first, .didattica:first').stop().slideDown();
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/5c2xh80y/)

---

You could accomplish the same thing using `nextUntil`:

```
jQuery(function () {
  var un= jQuery('.unique1, .unique2, .unique3, .unique4');
  un.click(function () {
    jQuery('.amministrazione, .didattica, a').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).nextUntil(un).stop().slideDown();
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ao4znwny/)

Comment: Thanks! It works. If I may.. I forgot one thing in the question: I also have some links after .didattica and .amministrazione.. how can I target them too (so they appear when .unique[] is clicked and disappear when another .unique is clicked..? See edited question to see where they are positioned. Sorry again for forgetting to specify this in the question..

Answer (score 0):

```
You can change your code with
```

`jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.unique1, .unique2, .unique3, .unique4').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = $(this).next('.amministrazione');
            newTarget= newTarget.add(newTarget.next());
            newTarget.slideDown()
        jQuery('.amministrazione, .didattica').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
});`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I forgot that below .amministrazione and .didattica I also have some links (not inside the divs though). They should also appear when .unique[] is clicked and disappear when another .unique[] is clicked. See edited question.. Sorry for forgetting this in the question.